# Where can I find the env var after I run "export WEBROOT=xxx" in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

Does the system store the var in file?

Or just store it in memory?

I can't find it in ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile...

Where can I find it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It lives in your shell's memory, and is copied into the memory of any commands that your shell executes. The environment is a property of the running process and is never written to disk; if you `export WEBROOT=blah`, exit your shell, and then restart it, you'll see that `WEBROOT` is now empty. (You can check this with `printenv` or just `echo $WEBROOT`.)

Several shell startup scripts, such as `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, contain commands to initialize certain environment variables to specified values. But these are simply recordings of `export` commands as you would run yourself at the prompt. They do not store the environment itself.

If you write C code, you may be familiar with the standard prototype for the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // ...
}
```

But actually, there is another argument to `main` that is typically omitted:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {
  // ...
}
```

This `envp` is where the environment lives -- it's set up by the kernel and pushed onto the stack above `main`, just like the program arguments. The standard Unix environment also provides the `environ` pointer which points to this area of memory, for usage by libc functions such as `getenv` and `setenv`.

When a program calls `exec`, the environment is also passed into that call, to be copied into the initial stack of the `exec`'d program. The full prototype for the syscall, `execve`, can be seen to take this pointer:

```
int execve(const char *path, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no single file where the envt variables are stored.

execute `printenv` on your terminal. It'll list all the envt variables declared in your system.

Read this for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107407/from-where-does-printenv-command-read-environment-variables-which-i-have-not-def